# Catboost understanding - Conversion of Categorical values

Tags: python, machine-learning, catboost

I have some silly question on catboost.

From the documentation of catboost, I understood that there are some permutation/shuffle between the rows, for the categorical data transformation.(https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic-docpage/#algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic)

I was trying to predict on a single observation to check if my model works, but I get an error. However with 2 observations, it works fine.

My question is, for the prediction of a catboost classifier, do we have to at least give 2 observations because of the permutation ? If yes, does the first observation have an impact on the output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catboost indeed has such a restriction. However, it has nothing to do with permutations, for they are applied only at the fitting stage.

The problem is that the same method `catboost.Pool._check_data_empty` is applied before `predict` as well as `fit`. And for fitting, having more than one observation is indeed crucial.

Now the checking function requires that `sum(x.shape)>2`, which is indeed strange. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
import catboost
import numpy as np
x_train3 = np.array([[1,2,3,], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
x_train1 = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
y_train = np.array([1,2,3])
x_test3_2 = np.array([[4,5,6], [5,6,7]])
x_test3_1 = np.array([[4,5,6,]])
x_test1_2 = np.array([[4], [5]])
x_test1_1 = np.array([[4]])
model3 = catboost.CatBoostRegressor().fit(x_train3, y_train)
model1 = catboost.CatBoostRegressor().fit(x_train1, y_train)
print(model3.predict(x_test3_2)) # OK
print(model3.predict(x_test3_1)) # OK
print(model1.predict(x_test1_2)) # OK
print(model1.predict(x_test1_1)) # Throws an error!
```

For now, you can do well by adding one or two more fake rows before calling `predict`. They will have no effect on the output for the original row.